# What functions do I need to display document names only

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display the document names from firebase using flutter. So I have a collection, named courses, that is the root. Then inside the collection i have 3 documents, with unique names. And each document has 4 fields.

I cant find a function that displays only the unique names of the documents, without having to refer to any of the 4 fields. I know i can assign a field as the unique id of each document, and refer to that field to display the documents, but i was wondering if there is a function that can just display the documents names without going into its fields. Something like displaying all documents names from a folder, without going into the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Edgar Torres As per my knowledge to get only names of documents from firestore without going to specific fields, you can use `DocumentSnapshot.id` property. This attribute assigns a unique identifier to each document.

hope this help!